# Should there be a comma in 'a 30-day, money-back guarantee'?

Tags: punctuation, commas, modifiers

Is a comma needed in the following phrases?

> 30-day, money-back guarantee
>   90-day, no-risk trial

If so, why? If not, why not?

I've seen them written both ways — with and without the comma — but certainly one way has to be more correct than the other.

Comment: Would omitting the comma cause confusion in either case? There is a faint possibility that 'a 30-day money-back guarantee' implies that for the subsequent 335 days say the guarantee is not of the money-back variety, whereas 'a 30-day, money-back guarantee' means that the guarantee lasts for 30 days and is of the money-back variety. The comma guarantees that both modifiers modify the noun. Compare a light blue jumper with a light, blue jumper.

Comment: Mr Ashworth, would you agree the commas are unneeded in 'a 10-pound 6-ounce baby', 'a 5-foot 10-inch woman', 'a 3-year 5-month 9-day project' and 'a 2-day 3-hour 10-second' event? Conversely, we could forgo the commas in 'The project lasted 3 years 5 months 9 days' and in 'The project lasted 3 years 5 months *and* 9 days. Agree to all?

Comment: DIFFERENT QUESTION! PROBABLY DUPE! However: If the guy paying you says put them in, I'd say they're needed. Check on the internet for things like "five foot six inch" and "five foot six inches" to see what is usual. I'd certainly not use commas. (Oh, and shouldn't 'Conversely be 'Likewise'?

Comment: Yes, it should have been 'Likewise'.

Comment: Do you mean a second comma, after 'money-back', or do you suggest removing the comma after '30-day'? I think both phrases are perfectly alright as they stand. '30-day', and money-back' are both adjectives which qualify 'guarantee'. Some people place what I think is called a 'Cambridge comma' after the final adjective, but most do not.

Comment: Remove the comma after the word "day" in each example is what I meant. Why or why not would it be correct to do so? What's the grammatical reason?

Comment: I see what you mean. It is not quite like saying 'an absolutely stupendous, well-organised, and enjoyable day out'. I suppose some might argue that it should be written '30-day-money-back guarantee'. But I think I would use the comma, as in 'a tall, thin, bedraggled-looking man'. On reflection I think I was wrong about the Cambridge comma. That is something else.

Comment: I think it's @TRomano that reminds us that the written comma is used to indicate pauses in *spoken* language. In that sense, I don't see one as more correct than the other, because it depends on how the speaker said the phrase. But if you mean which written version obeys some "law of writing," I suspect grammarians and style guides will differ. Or they might say insert a comma when it reflects a pause in spoken language. This seems particularly apt if what is written *is* reflecting spoken language.

Comment: ... though I think that question could do with a better answer. I shall offer one later.

Comment: @medica it wasn't closed earlier, and I could believe that someone who was musing on this question could forget that they'd asked about it, if they were someone who often asked questions as whippoorwill is.

Comment: @medica Mine's here too because I was answering this question while Janus was answering the other and now they're merged.

Comment: @JonHanna - OK, now I know I need glasses. Totally missed that!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In your example I would write either 'a light-blue jumper', or 'a blue-coloured light jumper'. Other than for this type of disambiguation I think it is largely a matter of personal preference as to whether one separates adjectives/adjectival phrases qualifying the same noun with commas.

Comment: @WS2 I might well do so on most days, but 'light-blue' has a wrong 'feel' to it. Many style guides recommend it prenominally to avoid the ambiguity, but the [BHG Stylebook](http://bhgstylebook.com/colors/) recommends against it (doubtless on style grounds): 'If the adjective immediately preceding a common color describes the particular hue, shade, or intensity, and could be used with many colors, do not hyphenate the color as a compound modifier: Toss the light green pillow on the chair. // In reading, the pause between the two successive adjectives would disambiguate; the comma reflects this.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, I don't know what BHG (Better Homes and Gardens) know about these things. What does the Thames Valley Auto Trader say? A light green Toyota Avensis?

Comment: If you read the info they provide, it seems more comprehensive hereabouts than many less unexpected sources. Looking up "Wearing a light-blue suit" on Google seems to indicate that the usual practice is to avoid hyphenating here (admittedly, some readings are ambiguous, but certainly many are obviously the compound adjective).

Comment: But isn't this just the result of the acceptance by society of sloppy English. The best way to disambiguate must be through employment of the hyphen. Whether the witness said the figure she saw was wearing a light-blue suit, or a blue lightweight suit, the way it is written in her signed statement to the police could be of vital importance. Accuracy of understanding in many instances takes vastly greater priority than 'style'.

Answer (score 4):

A comma is usually used between adjectives that are parallel, that is, modify the same head in a noun phrase. This usage is essentially just a listing comma: you put commas before all entries in a list (including or excepting the final one that also has an *and*, depending on whether you like the Oxford comma or not).

Example:

> A small, red, wooden(,) and cozy house.

Here, we have four adjectives that all modify *house*: the house is small, it is red, it is wooden, and it is cozy.

If we make a copular sentence out of this phrase, it becomes:

> The house is small, red, wooden, and cozy.

Conversely, no comma is used between an adjective and the thing that it modifies, so there is never a comma in “a wooden house”. It is important to note that adjectives do not just modify *nouns*: they modify *noun phrases*. And a noun phrase modified by an adjective *is also a noun phrase*. The following, then, is also perfectly correct:

> A small red wooden cozy house.

This means something different, though: it means that there is a [cozy house] (a noun phrase, a single unit), which is wooden. This [wooden [cozy house]] (another single unit) is red. And the [red [wooden [cozy house]]] (single unit again) is small.

If we make a copular sentence out of this, it becomes, in ‘stacked layers’:

> The house is cozy.
>   The cozy house is wooden.
>   The wooden cozy house is red.
>   The red wooden cozy house is small.

In this example, that gets a bit fanciful. It’s more natural to just describe a member of the category *houses* as being all four things, rather than take a member of the somewhat fanciful category *red wooden cozy houses* and describing it as red, etc.

In your example, however, things are different:

> A 30-day, money-back guarantee.
>   A 90-day, no-risk trial.

With the comma, these phrases describe a member of the category *guarantees*, which is then said to be both *30-day* and *money-back*; and a member of the category *trials*, which is said to be both *90-day* and *no-risk*. Without the commas, the categories are *money-back guarantees* and *no-risk trials*.

In copular form, with the comma:

> The guarantee is 30-day and money-back.
>   The trial is 90-day and no-risk.

And without the comma:

> The money-back guarantee is 30-day.
>   The no-risk trial is 90-day.

Of these, the latter make more logical sense to me, but there’s nothing actually wrong with the former. Either version, with or without the comma, is perfectly correct; they just mean slightly different things.

(Neither *30-day/90-day*, *money-back*, nor *no-risk* is really a true adjective; they’re more like noun adjuncts. This means that they are limited to being used attributively, rather than predicatively, so the copular sentences here are all quite strange-sounding, no matter how you phrase them.)

Comment: This is a great answer. Gotta keep this around.

Comment: The problems with mergings. I probably wouldn't have bothered answering if this had been on the question I chose to answer on, though at least I do cover this ground in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

A general rule is that a comma should be used if the two modifiers both modify the noun, rather than the first one modifying the noun-phrase formed by the second modifier and the noun.

> A heavy, bulky box.
>
> A lovely hand-made toy.

*Heavy* applies to *box* about as much as *bulky* does.

*Lovely* applies to "hand-made toy".

Three guides can help decide if you have the first ("coördinate modifier") case rather than the second ("cumulative modifier") case:

1. Could you put *and* between them without changing the meaning (but being wordier and hence changing emphasis).
2. Could you switch them around without changing the meaning.
3. Are they at the same level in terms of modifier order (amount or number, general opinion, specific opinion or quality, size, age, shape, colour, origin or material, purpose or qualifier, noun-as-modifier).

These essentially amount to the same thing; they're different ways of spotting the same thing going on.

(They can be complicated if a pair of adjectives become idiomatic, as then re-arranging will sound wrong even though its grammatically fine).

The question of modifier order is complicated here because nouns turned to modifiers ("30 days" to *30-day*, "money back" [from the noun *money*] to *money-back*, "no risk" to *no-risk*) always tend to come at the end, and since we've pairs of such we're likely to order between them as we would adjectives.

I can't see "money-back, 30-day guarantee" being used, but I'm honestly not sure if that's because *30-day* is a size and *money-back* a qualifier or because "money-back guarantee" is an idiom I'm used to hearing. I'm slightly more inclined to have "no-risk, 90-day trial", but not a lot and I wouldn't expect "90-day and no-risk trial".

In all, I think "the money-back guarantee is for 30 days" is more plausible than "the 30-day guarantee is money-back"; the modifiers aren't at the same level, they aren't easily switched, and they don't work equally well with *and*.

So:

> 30-day money-back guarantee
>
> 90-day no-risk trial

Are the "correct" versions.

But the scare-quotes around "correct" are there for a reason.

If I'm trying to sell something and to use the guarantee or trial to do so, I may very well want to emphasise "30 day" and "money-back" as individual qualities. Likewise "no-risk" and "90-day". A pause between the two will help do that, and that's a perfectly valid reason to use a comma:

> 30-day, money-back guarantee
>
> 90-day, no-risk trial

Screw the rules, I've got rhetoric!

(It's also a reason why I might choose to put "no-risk" in front and have "no-risk, 90-day trial", as much as putting a length first would be more common, as it can allow for more emphasis on "no-risk").

Indeed, I think this is in itself a good example of the difficulties of talking about rules with comma placement, as we've a perfectly good rule that matches most usage that would have us not use a comma but also a perfectly good reason to put a comma in anyway.

Comment: +1 Interesting, and always a treat to see good answers explained a bit differently.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a comma. Two things define the guarantee - that it lasts 30 days and that money-back is the compensation.

Comment: Unless there is confusion that the guarantee may be for "thrity day-money-backs", does the comma add any meaning, or is it just a style choice?

Answer (score 0):

> a 30-day, money-back guarantee
>
> a 60-day, no-risk obligation

A 30 day long money-back guarantee.

--> No comma required.

> The 30-day long **,** (comma) money back guaranteed **,**(comma) guarantee,
>   guarantees that you get your money back, guaranteed, if you are
>   unhappy with the product during the 30-day (long) (**no comma**) money
>   back (no comma) guarantee.